# Use of setApplicationBadgeString on iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, iphone-privateapi

I am developing a piece of code which where I would like to dynamically update the badge of the application, so show its status. Pretty regular.

I am using this following API

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationBadgeString:@"x"];
```

My problem is that when I try to use this API multiple times within an application session, the badge which is displayed on the Springboard does not get updated.

My use is

```
//Check if user is logged in then
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationBadgeString:@"On"];

//wait for network event

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationBadgeString:@"Off"];
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Nitin

Comment: I'm also having an issue with this on iOS7, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing works perfectly on my end.

This is an undocumented API, so I can't confirm, but perhaps it needs to be executed on the main thread, not a background one.

Also, be advised that because this *is* a private API, its use is grounds for rejection from the AppStore.